# Get Microsoft Word contents in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on an objective-c project, and I want to get Microsoft Word contents.
I have tried to find ways in github but did not get answer.
What should I do?

Comment: TextEdit can read MS Word files, and Apple provides the full source code as a sample (and it doesn't rely on code from GitHub). Happy hunting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read MS Word files with `NSAttributedString` with document type: `NSDocFormatTextDocumentType`

Comment: I could not work out. Could you please give me an example? thanks.

Comment: First thanks for the answer. I have worked out with MS Word. But I find this method does not work for other kind of file like .pdf .ppt .xls. And I am stuck in here for a day. Do you know some resolution? thanks a lot.

Comment: @Zhai There is list of document supported types : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsattributedstringdocumenttype?language=objc there is also xls. For PDF you can look at `PDFKit`. If you need just display documents you can use `WebView`.

Comment: I have tried all types but there is no one work out for xls and ppt. I need to get the contents, so WebView is not suitable for me.